# How do you break up a nested list into a dataframe where each embedded list becomes a separate column?

Tags: r, dataframe

My goal is to take a nested list as such:

```
list1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
list2 <- list(6,7,8,9,10)
list3 <- list(11,12,13,14,15)

nested_list <- list(list1, list2, list3)
```

and create a dataframe with the number of columns = number of lists embedded in the nested list. In other words, I am trying to get list1, list2, and list3 all placed into separate columns of a data frame.

I have tried using some functions from tidyr such as "unnest_wider" but haven't had much luck. Most functions out there are built to turn each nested list into an observation (row), not columns. I know I could run some sort of loop to do this, but that approach isn't very efficient.

Comment: `do.call(cbind, nested_list)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `unclass(df)` with any `data.frame`, you can see that (despite the attributes) a `data.frame` bascially already has the data structure you have. Knowing this we only have to `unlist` the lists inside the list.

In a one-liner:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(nested_list, unlist))
#>   c.1..2..3..4..5. c.6..7..8..9..10. c.11..12..13..14..15.
#> 1                1                 6                    11
#> 2                2                 7                    12
#> 3                3                 8                    13
#> 4                4                 9                    14
#> 5                5                10                    15
```

Or using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble(nested_list, .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
  unnest(everything())
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> * `` -> ...3
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    ...1  ...2  ...3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     6    11
#> 2     2     7    12
#> 3     3     8    13
#> 4     4     9    14
#> 5     5    10    15
```

The reason the column names are a mess is that the list elements have no names. If they had names you would see they become column names in both solutions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the simple explanation. I am relatively new to the tidyverse world and how "tibbles" operate as opposed to dataframes but I think it makes more sense to start getting used to them. Is there any scenario where a dataframe is better than a tibble?

Comment: That's a whole question of it's own! I don't think so though. I remember `df$new_colum <- value` (assigne values to non-existing colums) caused some problems with tibble in the past. But that's what `mutate` is for. In this scenario it doesn't matter though. The difference here is `unnest(everything())` as opposed to `lapply(nested_list, unlist)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would go

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, nested_list))
```